# Javascript shortcut, to append string into all the values of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array = ["a", "b", "c"];`

What I want is i have an string let us say "Hello", that I want to append to each and every value of this array.

My expected output is something like

```
["Hello_a", "Hello_b", "Hello_c"]
```

Is there any shortcut in javascript to perform this operation, without using any loop .

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: `.map(x => 'Hello_' + x)` - does it count as a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `Array.prototype.map()` at this context,

```
var yourArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
var transformed = yourArray.map(function(item){
  return "Hello_" + item;
});
console.log(transformed); // ["Hello_a", "Hello_b", "Hello_c"]
```

Also you can use fat Arrow functions if users of you are updated with latest browsers.

```
var yourArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
var transformed = yourArray.map(item => "Hello_" + item);
console.log(transformed); // ["Hello_a", "Hello_b", "Hello_c"]
```

As a side note, you have to sure about arrow functions that it will forcibly use `lexical this` inside of it.